# fabricjs canvas occasionally loads objects incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

This might be hard for me to present but basically my canvas is rendering incorrectly after sometimes an initial load of my code or a refresh after a few good attempts. Usually it's the text, it'll sometimes not load a font or it will be off in its positioning on the canvas, until I refresh (but not always).

I've tried fidgeting with where tags are, having all of the code locally, but haven't had any luck; eventually it happens again. Do you see anything that I could improve? Thank you in advance.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- fabric.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <!-- My Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel|Monsieur+La+Doulaise|Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Choose your...</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <h6 class="dropdown-header">Number</h6>
            <a onclick="one()" class="dropdown-item">One</a>
            <a onclick="two()" class="dropdown-item">Two</a>
            <h6 class="dropdown-header">Font</h6>
            <a class="dropdown-item" id="cinzel" style="font-family:cinzel;">Cinzel</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" id="monsieurladoulaise" style="font-family:Monsieur La Doulaise;">Monsieur La Doulaise</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" id="tangerine" style="font-family:tangerine;">Tangerine</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="window.location.reload(true)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Restart</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- My JS File -->
  <script src="verses.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor:pointer;
}

a.dropdown-item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

And then I've got my JS file which has a few functions that add shapes to the canvas.

```
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
};

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setHeight(412);
canvas.setWidth(637);

var dynamicText = new fabric.IText('', {left: 8, top: 8, fontSize: 12})
canvas.add(dynamicText);

function one() {
  dynamicText.setText('Some Text');
  canvas.renderAll();
}
function two() {
  dynamicText.setText('Some Text');
  canvas.renderAll();
}

canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Some Text', {
  left: 480,
  top: 60,
  fontFamily: 'cinzel',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: 27,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false,
  selectable: true,
  lockRotation: true,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true,
  align: 'mid',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  centeredScaling: true,

//fonts
document.getElementById('cinzel').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", "cinzel");
  canvas.renderAll();
});
document.getElementById('monsieurladoulaise').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", "Monsieur La Doulaise");
  canvas.renderAll();
});
document.getElementById('tangerine').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", "tangerine");
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Does anything stick out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because your fabric is loading before google font load.
So after refresh, all the things working well because font was loaded successfully when refresh.

You can detect font load like this.

```
document.fonts.ready.then(function () {
   alert('cinzel loaded? ' + document.fonts.check('cinzel'));  // true
});

document.fonts.onloadingdone = function (fontFaceSetEvent) {
   alert('onloadingdone we have ' + fontFaceSetEvent.fontfaces.length + ' font faces loaded');
};
```

Before font load, you can add spinner and you can load the fabricjs at that time.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Would I apply this to every font? And that'd force the font to load?

Comment: `document.fonts.ready.then` is called after all fond load finish, you can check the required fonts ready to use